# Q: How can I print an EXCEL / VBA Userform in landscape format?

Tags: excel, vba, printing, userform, landscape

I have created a chronicle as an Excel file with VBA using Userforms to display the content. With a button in the Userform I can print the active Userform with Me.PrintForm. The result is a page in portrait format, but about one third of the Userform is not printed.  How can I achieve printing in landscape format? HWi

Comment: can you show a pictur of your file and Userform?

Answer (score 1):

I could not find any way to do that, your best way is to use the Snipping Tool (or the Print Screen button on your keybord).

https://www.google.com/search?q=snipping+tool

Answer (score 0):

This can be done only using a trick. I mean, to print an empty sheet with only the form on it. I am not the creator of the next code. I found it, some time before, on internet, used it and saved in my collection of interesting code pieces.

1. Copy the next line on top of your form module (in the declarations area):

   `Option Explicit`

   `Private Declare PtrSafe Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, _
      ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As LongPtr))`

   `Const VK_SNAPSHOT = 44
   Const VK_LMENU = 164
   Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 2
   Const KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 1`
2. Create the next sub in your form module:

   `Private Sub PrintForm()`

   ```
   DoEvents
   keybd_event VK_LMENU, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0
   keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0
   keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY + _
       KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0
   keybd_event VK_LMENU, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY + _
       KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0`
   DoEvents
   Workbooks.Add
   Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
   ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Bitmap", link:=False, _
       DisplayAsIcon:=False
   ```

   `ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
       'added to force landscape
       ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape`

   ```
   With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
       .PrintTitleRows = ""
       .PrintTitleColumns = ""
   End With

   ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""

   With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
       .LeftHeader = ""
       .CenterHeader = ""
       .RightHeader = ""
       .LeftFooter = ""
       .CenterFooter = ""
       .RightFooter = ""
       .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
       .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
       .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1)
       .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1)
       .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
       .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
       .PrintHeadings = False
       .PrintGridlines = False
       .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
       .PrintQuality = 300
       .CenterHorizontally = True
       .CenterVertically = True
       .Orientation = xlLandscape
       .PaperSize = xlPaperA4
       .Order = xlDownThenOver
       .BlackAndWhite = False
       .FitToPagesWide = 1
       .FitToPagesTall = 1
   End With
   ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1
   ActiveWorkbook.Close False
   ```

   `End Sub`
3. Call the above `Sub` from a form button. It will print on your default printer...

   `Sub ButtonX_Click()
       PrintForm
   End Sub`